# What are the differences between CollectionViewSource, ICollectionView, ListCollectionView, IList and BindingListCollectionView and their use cases?

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource, icollectionview, listcollectionview

What are the differences between `CollectionViewSource`, `ICollectionView`, `ListCollectionView`, `IList` and `BindingListCollectionView`?
When and where to use all these collections?

I know the main use of `CollectionViewSource`, but I'm not clear with when to use these, because in XAML I use `CollectionViewSource` for grouping, sorting, etc. and when I want it in code-behind I use `ListCollectionView`.

Could you explain the exact differences and the use case(s) of each type of collection?

Comment: Do you really need `IList` explained?

Comment: @jon , I know _It Represents a non-generic collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index_ but my question is can't i achieve this using normal _List(Of T)_, perhaps i wuld be wrong ,if u explain when and where and what is the differences betrween these things it wuld be helpfull for me better understanding. Thnks

Comment: @Selva generic List is a specific implementation of IList.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the CollectionView is a means of building a Master Ditail View in the simplest possible way in WPF.
First of all, I would like to introduce you to the fallback mechanism.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="planets" Type="{x:Type local:Planets}">
            <local:Planets Name="Earth" Diameter="12,756 km" Mass="5.97 10^24kg" Density="5514 kg/m³"/>
            <local:Planets Name="Mars" Diameter="6792 km" Mass="0.642 10^24kg" Density="3933 kg/m³"/>
            <local:Planets Name="Jupiter" Diameter="142,984 km" Mass="1898 10^24kg" Density="1326 kg/m³"/>
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel DataContext="{StaticResource planets}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name" Width="125"/>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mass}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Density}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

```cs
public class Planets
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Diameter { get; set; }
        public string Mass { get; set; }
        public string Density { get; set; }
    }
```

We have a simple array of type `Planets`.
The *DisplayMemberPath-Property* is also `Name` set, so the planet name is displayed in the `ListBox`. In addition to the `ListBox`, the details of the respective planet are displayed in a `TextBlock`. Vourla, there we have our working master detail view with implicit use of the `CollectionView` via the fallback mechianism

[image]

Since the property `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` is set, the WPF generates a `Default-CollectioView` in the background and saves the object selected in the `ListBox` in the `CurrentItem-Property`. It is now the case that the `Binding` of the `TextBlock` first searches for the `Property` on the `Planets[]` Array; it doesn’t find anything there, but the fallback mechanism forwards it to the `CurrentItem-Property` of the `Default-CollectionView`.
It is also possible to reference the `CurrentItem-Property` of the `Default-CollectionView` directly. To do this, do a simple `(/)` in front of the `Property` in the `Binding`.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding /Name}"/>
```

The fallback mechanism only works if the `Path-Property` of the `Binding` is set.

`CollectionViewSource` is derived from `CollectionView` and is a proxy to provide certain `Properties` such as `Source` or `View`.

There are three other classes derived from `CollectionView`, these are `ItemCollection`, `ListCollectionView` and `BindingListCollectionView`. The *Interfaces* of the *Classes*, i.e. the types in front of them `(I)`, are there to avoid a direct coupling with the *Classes*. The principle that is followed is called ***Dependencie Injection***

The three *Classes* `ItemCollection`, `ListCollectionView` and `BindingListCollectionView` are designed for different purposes. `ItemCollection` thus provides an `IEnumerabl`e, `ListCollectionView` an `IList` and `BindingListCollectionView` an `IBindingList` Object. Thus, different types are provided for different purposes.

All in all, the `CollectionView` is a powerful **WPF** tool; you can sort, group, etc. and display details.

I hope this helps you further. Greetings Michael

Comment: This is a bit of a disadvantage, but I have now first seen that the question is from 2013. Sorry for that, I'm just a beginner. I hope somebody continues anyway.